# Any time control with hours, minutes and seconds in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, timepicker

I want to have a time picker control where I can set hours, minutes and seconds. The default timepicker control does not have second included. What is the easiest way to have seconds value in timepicker control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `TimePicker` indeed does not support seconds input. You could subclass `TimePicker` and manually extend it to support this scenario, but this might prove quite complex, because you would have to not only modify the template of the control itself, but you would have to edit the `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` to support seconds input. It may even not be possible at all, and may be an overkill.

I think the better and easier solution would be to use the [`TextBoxMask` extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask) which is part of the **Windows Community Toolkit**. This allows you to define a custom format of a `TextBox`, which could look like this:

```
<TextBox extensions:TextBoxMask.CustomMask="5:[0-5]"
                     extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="99:59:59" />
```

This `TextBox` will support input in the format `hh:mm:ss`. By default the `Mask` supports characters `a` for letters, `9` for digits 0-9 and `*` for any character. You can define custom mask chars using `CustomMask` which is what I did here to make sure the tens of minutes and seconds are limited to fifties (00-59).

Another solution could be to create a custom control that combines the normal built-in `TimePicker` with a `TextBox` just for seconds, but I think the `TextBoxMask` is a better and user friendlier solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I agree with your suggestion. But I might need to try the custom control creation approach.

Comment: Any idea how to reset a textbox (programatically in UWP) with this mask to the initial value "__:__:__"? I tried nearly everything. string.Empty does only delete one char, I could loop multiple string.Empty but there surely must be a better way. In UWP there is no .Clear() on textboxes. It works well manually, but when there is already a value, I cannot set one programatically again, only when reset it works again, very strange.

Comment: Hey @Martin-Zikmund. Have you tried anything like this for Uno Platform?

Comment: Hello Christian! I suppose support will be added when WinUI 3 goes open source, because then it will be easy to port the TimePicker control 

Answer (score 0):

(+ 1) Martin Zikmund

I would just to improve a bit the answer of Martin Zikmund.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask)

> TextBox Mask property has 3 build in variable characters
>
> 'a' which represents [a-Z] '9' which represents [0-9] '*' which represents
> a or 9

For 24 hours format:

**XAML**

```
<TextBox ui:TextBoxExtensions.CustomMask="0:[0-2],1:[0-9],5:[0-5]" 
         ui:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="01:59:59" x:Name="tbTime" TextChanged="tbTime_TextChanged"/>
```

**Code**

```
private void tbTime_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
   string textBoxText = textBox.Text; 
          
   if (IsValidTimeFormat(textBoxText))
   {
      // Yep
   }
   else
   {
      // Nope
   }
}

// Check if the string is valid TimeSpan
public bool IsValidTimeFormat(string input)
{
     TimeSpan dummyOutput;
     return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
}
```

**Explanation of  ui:TextBoxExtensions.CustomMask="0:[0-2],1:[0-9],5:[0-5]"
and  ui:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="01:59:59"**

0:[0-2] means that in any place we have insert 0 (zero) in
ui:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="01:59:59" is allowed to input numbers 0-2.

In fact instead of 0 could be any char or number because it is like a variable name. So you can type like 3:[0-2] and use it here ui:TextBoxExtensions.Mask="31:59:59".